# Updating .po files without restarting lighty

Tags: lighttpd, gettext

We are running PHP with gettext on the lighttpd web server. When we update the .po/.mo files with new translations, we have to restart lighty for the new translations to appear.

Is lighty caching the translations?

Anyone know how to avoid restarting lighty?

Thanks!